# Find all physical interfaces in FreeBSD

Tags: shell-script, networking, freebsd

I have a use case to find all physical (no virtual or vlan interfaces) on FreeBSD.

How can I get a count of the number of physical interfaces on a box consistently regardless of any virtual interface or vlan config?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're looking for something along this line:

```
pciconf -lv | grep network | wc -l
```

Also, you may get a list of the interfaces like this:

```
pciconf -lv | grep ethernet -B4 | grep class= | cut -d@ -f1
```